# Get date of some UNIX time

Tags: bash, date, unix-timestamp

How can I convert UNIX time to date format?
Smth like

```
$> date ???? 1300000000
Mar 13 2011 07:06:40 GMT
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `date` command might understand the `@` prefix. Try:

```
$ date -d @1300000000
Sun Mar 13 08:06:40 CET 2011
```

Comment: Yep. If you want to match the original question's output exactly, you can force the time zone to GMT as follows: `env TZ=GMT date -d @1300000000`.

Comment: @psmears, yes, or with the `-u` option.

Comment: Be *very* careful with setting `TZ` to values, as `date` will not produce any indication of an error in case you use a non-existing timezone for `TZ`, but print a UTC time and claim it is the time for your non-existing timezone: `env TZ=XYZ date` will give your something like `Sun Mar 13 12:11:21 XYZ 2011`.

Comment: @ndim: True, but since for these purposes GMT and UTC are effectively the same, that's not a problem in this specific case :-)

Comment: @psmears: To the contrary: The case of GMT and UTC is especially dangerous, as you will not even notice the issue with the GMT and UTC values being the same, and then risk assuming that `TZ=what/ever` will just work as it obviously worked with `TZ=GMT`, right? :-)

Comment: @ndim: So you're saying that all cases that work are dangerous because other cases might not work? ;-) I take your point that TZ should be used with care because it fails silently, but I think that's going a bit far :)

Answer (score 0):

If -d doesn't work for you, thats probably because it only works like that for GNU date.

For BSD, OSX, etc. one would ordinarily use:

```
date -r 1300000000
```